# Ubuntu just disappeared, cant boot onto it anymore

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I completely wiped both of my HDDs this weekend and installed Windows10 on C: and Ubuntu on E: again (yes I had a dualboot before my wipe). Everything worked fine, grub showed up and it showed Windows Boot Manager and Ubuntu in my BIOS boot options.

I then installed CS:GO for Windows on my E: drive and Ubuntu is just gone, I cannot boot into it anymore. No Grub Menu, No boot option for it in the bios.

I have fast boot/secure boot turned off and I'm pretty sure the installation of CS:GO on my E: drive caused this problem. What did I do wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the acronym CS:GO, so I Googled it. The top hit was for *Counter-Strike: Global Offensive,* which looks like a game. Was this a Windows game, or an Ubuntu game? If the former, you shouldn't have been able to install it on the same partition as Ubuntu (you say you installed both to `E:`) unless you used the deprecated [WUBI](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) method of installing Ubuntu.

This raises a couple of important questions:

- **Are you booting in BIOS mode, in EFI mode, or a mixture of the two?** This is *always* a critical question when diagnosing boot problems. Your description of having "BIOS" (probably actually EFI) boot options of "Windows Boot Manager" and "Ubuntu" suggests EFI-mode, since BIOS-mode booting does not name OSes in this way -- at least, not in the firmware's built-in boot manager.
- **Did you use WUBI?** AFAIK, WUBI only works for BIOS-mode booting, and it's no longer recommended even for that. Your claim that you installed both Ubuntu and the game to `E:` suggests use of WUBI; but perhaps you erred in your description or your Windows drive assignments changed at some point. Note that Ubuntu does not give drive letters like Windows, so if you installed Ubuntu in the normal way, describing it as being on `E:` is meaningless; you'd do better to say what partition, as identified in Ubuntu, holds the OS, like `/dev/sda5` or `/dev/sdb3`.

Answering these questions may help with a more specific analysis of *your* problem. The usual recommendation in your situation is to run [Boot Repair.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) This tool can fix some common boot problems, including some that have the symptoms you describe; however, it might not work, and in rare cases it can actually make matters worse. Note that the question of your boot mode (BIOS vs. EFI) is very important, and it's critical that the emergency system you use to run Boot Repair run in the same mode as your regular OS installations. See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootmode.html) for information on determining your boot mode -- both in Windows and in the emergency disk you boot to run Boot Repair.

If you run Boot Repair and it doesn't help, please post the URL it provides; that will give us more information about your configuration. If you're not sure if you should use Boot Repair, you can go ahead and run it, but select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here.

Comment: Yeah Counter-Strike: Global Offensive WAS a game for Windows, but its playable on Linux too.

I did not use WUBI to install Ubuntu, i used an USB-Stick for Windows and for Ubuntu. However i converted my C drive to GPT, because i was running windows in BIOS compatibility mode before, but my E drive is still MBR, i dont know if that matters.
When i started my PC and press F11, which is the key to access the boot order/options, i did see "Windows Boot Manager" and "ubuntu" on it. 
TL;DR: Both OS's are running in EFI Mode, and i did not use WUBI.